# Get Document Id When Using Pre / Save Middleware Mongoose Model Methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I need to get document ID from post middle but it doesn't exist sometimes when I findAndUpdate.

Anyone know why?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema,
      ShiftSchema = new Schema({
        _id: { type: String, 'default': shortid.generate},
        creator_id: { type: String, required: true },
        project_id: { type: String, required: true }
      }),
      _ = require('underscore');

var when_to_notify = ['save', 'findByIdAndUpdate', 'findOneAndUpdate', 'findByIdAndUpdate'];

_.each(when_to_notify, function(pre_func) {
  ShiftSchema.post(pre_func, function() {
    otherFunc(this);
  });
})

function otherFunc(self) {
  doSomethingWith(self._id)
  // typeof self._id == 'undefined' == true 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a certain set of functions are supported for middleware document and query functions.

Document middleware supports:

- init
- validate
- save
- remove

Query middleware supports these Model and Query functions:

- count
- find
- findOne
- findOneAndRemove
- findOneAndUpdate
- insertMany
- update

Another factor may be that:

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but
>   important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document
>   being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have
>   a reference to the document being updated, so this refers to the query
>   object rather than the document being updated.

In your example you are mixing query and document middleware with the same function so the context will be different. The document middleware signature actually takes a document argument:

```
schema.post('save', function(doc) {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
});
```